# How to fit 100% of an image to a Jumbotron

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Souplesse</h1>
        <p>Be a Good Sport</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the following CSS:

```
.jumbotron {
  background-image:url('piscine.jpg');
  height:300px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  border-bottom:1px solid #ff6a00
}
.jumbotron .container {
  position:relative;
  top:50px;
}
```

My image is far too large to fit my height of 300px but I would like it to auto-resize and fit the height, so I can see all of my image. This must be simple but I can't see what changes need to be made.

Thanks

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you would like the background image to fit the height of your jumbotron, but don't care about if it stretches to the entire width:

`.jumbotron { background-size: auto 100%; }`

If you want the background image to cover the entire height AND width of the jumbotron and you do *not* care about the image's aspect ratio:

`.jumbotron {background-size: 100% 100%; }`

If you want the background image to be cover the entire height AND width the jumbotron but you *DO* care about the image's aspect ratio:

`.jumbotron {  background-size: cover; }`

That last option will have some of the image cut off if the jumbotron has a different aspect ratio than the image, but you can specify how the image is positioned with the background position property:

```
.jumbotron {
    /* Image in the center of container */
    background-position: center center;

    /*  OR Image in the center top of the container */
    background-position: center top;

    /*  OR Image in the center bottom of the container  */
    background-position: center bottom;
}
```

Comment: Cheers Pete - this covers all bases and is some excellent knowledge. Thanks for  sharing.

Comment: My challenge with using "cover" is when the client wants the entire image to always be visible at 100% width. Currently I'm working on a page where the image width spans the entire browser, but the bottom of the image gets cut off when viewing on large screens.

Comment: [`background-size: cover;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size#contain) might be a good option for you then. "It scales the image as large as possible within its container without cropping or stretching the image."

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.jumbotron {
  background-image:url('piscine.jpg');
  height:300px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: auto 100%;
  border-bottom:1px solid #ff6a00
}
```

Note the:

```
background-size: auto 100%;
```

The first value is the width, the second value is the height. It is compliant to use px or % for those values.

Comment: This semi-works however you'll find that when you zoom in and out of the page (at least in Chrome, which I am using) the image will stop fitting.